# Force loading all projects with lightweight solution load enabled

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studion 2017 and lightweight solution load enabled. This is a great performance improvement, especially when I am just switching between different branches.

However, sometimes I want to load every project inside my solution. Currently I right click my solution in solution explorer and open *Configuration manager* which does what I want (but shows configuration manager) afterwards.

[image: solution load]

Is there a better way to achive this, preferable in the background so I can continue typing while visual studio loads all projects in the background.

Comment: Check the bottom of [this web page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/lightweight-solution-load-extension-impact) for a config tip to make it more visible.  And consider using the email address you find there, it isn't terribly obvious what you want.